# PHP see how many characters are equal

Tags: php, regex, compare

I have a string full of values that are separated by a comma. Needless to say this can be done with `$strings = explode(',',$fullstring);`.

Now, I need to compare a user-submitted-value to this value to see 'how equal' it is. Ideally I'd like to check that maximum one letter/symbol/number/... is not equal. For example, if the hardcoded string is 'table':

- 'tabl' would be true
- 'tablz' would be true
- 'tab' would be false

If you understand what I mean. Of course the strings can also contain spaces, apostrophes, numeric values. I really have no idea how I should get started on this. I've already set up a filter to check whether the value is equal (using `if(in_array(strtolower($userValue),array_map('strtolower',$strings)))`), but in the else clause I need some method to detect what I just explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the functionality you're looking for is best served by levenshtein.

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php for examples and a description of how to use it.

Comment: Whoah neat, I'd never heard about that! Searched the web for something, had no idea it would be this simple!

Comment: Any idea how it handles capital letters? Don't really see anything in the docs, but does it handle a capital vs lowercase as a replacement?

Comment: The distance consider them different, but you can apply some "filter" to your two string first, like converting them both to lower case.

Comment: the function is case sensitive. use strtolower first if you want an exact match

Comment: Yeah I tested it out in the mean time, works like a charm! Thanks folks!

Answer (score 3):

calculate Levenshtein distance between the two strings: http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php and check if the distance is less than some threshold value.